# cursor position after invoking clang-format

Tags: clang-format

I'm writing a plugin for some editor to use `clang-format`.

How to get the new position of the cursor after invoking `clang-format`?  (I pass the original position to `clang-format` by `--cursor=<uint>`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `clang-format` gets input from *stdin*, it will output the new cursor position first.  I didn't try it before...

```
$ cat a.cpp | clang-format --cursor=5
{ "Cursor": 5, "IncompleteFormat": false } # <= here
int main() {}
```

The above approach works only when using just ONE cursor.  
However, sometimes we need to use multi-cursor or there is a selected region, I wonder if there is an efficient method to get any number of new positions.